# After thunderstorm, monitor won't turn on

Tags: display, power-supply, hardware-failure

As a result of thunderstorm I had a power outage in my apartment. I had unplugged all the power cords of the computer during the storm but after the power came back the monitor wouldn't turn on.

I am using a HP 2311 GT monitor. I tried unplugging all the cords in the power strip and plugging them in again but it did not work. The indicator light of the monitor is not glowing either.

Comment: If you have already swapped cables and ports, i am ready to say its done

Comment: I had plugged the cords correctly

Answer (score 0):

Two things might happen. If you have an UPS then it could have affected your CPU/motherboard, but not directly your monitor. And if there wasn't any UPS, then the plugs were connected to different plug holes. So it might be like this: the moment you heard a lightning it had already damaged your monitor. Even when you keep the switch off during a lightning a sudden huge flow of current might have affected.... Use a voltage stabilizer.